# Как в Navigation architecture отобразить navigation drawer при нажатии на кнопку "гамбургера"?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation-drawer, navigation-architecture

Пробую [Navigation architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/) все довольно неплохо работает с нижней навигацией, но хочу добавить еще боковое меню т.к. в toolbar есть для этого кнопка, но при ее нажатии я получаю ошибку `NavController back stack is empty`.
Сам `navigation drawer` открывается если провести пальцем от края экрана и навигация по нему работает, единственное чего не могу сделать это открытие по нажатию на кнопку "гамбургера".

#### Activity:

```
class EntryActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.entry_activity)
        val host = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.host_fragment) as NavHostFragment ?: return
        val navController = host.navController
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,navController,container)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView,navController)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(drawerNavigation,navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return findNavController(R.id.host_fragment).navController.navigateUp()
    }
}
```

#### Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
tools:context=".EntryActivity">
    <fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"/>

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
    android:name="dev.serble.fines.ui.entry.BottomNavigationFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/drawerNavigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity = "start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_nav" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

#### Ошибка которая появляется если нажать на кнопку:

```
07-06 12:48:32.131 26936-26936/dev.serble.fines E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: dev.serble.fines, PID: 26936
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NavController back stack is empty
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.popBackStack(NavController.java:230)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigateUp(NavController.java:324)
        at dev.serble.fines.EntryActivity$override.onSupportNavigateUp(EntryActivity.kt:48)
        at dev.serble.fines.EntryActivity$override.access$dispatch(EntryActivity.kt)
        at dev.serble.fines.EntryActivity.onSupportNavigateUp(EntryActivity.kt)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:203)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper$1.onClick(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:188)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 1):

Стоит только написать вопрос на stackoverflow как ответ находится.
Для того что бы кнопка заработала нужно в активности переопределить один метод.

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        when(item?.itemId){
            android.R.id.home ->{
                if (container.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
                    container.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                }else{
                    container.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Всегда так было, еще во времена до появления Navigation ;)